# Different proof of fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-explanation

I found this proof sketch in Rosenlicht's book. I get the overall idea, but i don't get why we can write $f(z)$ in the way shown in c). I would be grateful if someone explained this proof to me. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: A similar proof appears in Rudin's PMA.

Answer (score 2):

You can write $f(z)$ as a polynomial in $z-\zeta$. If you subtract off the constant term, which is $f(\zeta)$, you get a polynomial divisible by $(z-\zeta)$. If we let $m$ be the largest power of $(z-\zeta)$ that divides $f(z)-f(\zeta)$, then $\dfrac{f(z)-f(\zeta)}{(z-\zeta)^m}$ has a nonzero constant term, so let $a$ be this constant term and let $g(z)$ be the quotient of $\dfrac{f(z)-f(\zeta)}{a(z-\zeta)^m}-1$ by $(z-\zeta)$.

Comment: How can I write $f(z)$ as a polynomial in $z-\zeta$? Thanks

Comment: Write $w = z-\zeta$, and expand $g(w) := f(z) = f(w+\zeta)$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Sorry, but how it will become a polynomial in $z-\zeta$, i.e. how will you get powers $(z-\zeta)^n$?

Comment: @luka5z $g$ is a polynomial in $w$. When you put $z-\zeta$ in for $w$, you get a polynomial in $z-\zeta$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I still don't get it how $f(\zeta)$ is a constant term of that polynomial...

Comment: For example, if $f(z) = z^3-5z^2+3z+7$, and $\zeta = 2$, then $f(w+\zeta) = f(w+2) = (w+2)^3-5(w+2)^2+3(w+2)+7$. According to wolfram, expanding this gives $f(w+2)=w^3+w^2-5w+1$. Substituting $z-2$ back in for $w$, we get that $f(z-2) = (z-2)^3+(z-2)^2-5(z-2)+1$ - this is a polynomial in $z-2$. To find the constant term of this polynomial, you plug in zero for $w$, just as you would for any polynomial. Here that's equivalent to plugging in $2$ for $z$, which is how you get that the constant term of the polynomial in $z-2$ is $f(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you show that all the complex derivatives of $f(z)$ exist (which makes $f(z)$ holomorphic), Taylor series can be used to derive this formula.

Such a formula can also be written for any holomorphic function. If the modulus of the holomorphic function has a minima (for example when its modulus is unbounded above large radial value $|z|$= $\sqrt{x^{2}+y^2}$ , z=x+iy ), then the minima must be zero.